# Some machines with Kaspersky can't connect to Skype network

Tags: skype, connection, blocking, kaspersky

That is very weird, some machines on my domain can't connect to Skype when Kaspersky is installed/active. And even if do a fresh install on the same machines Skype stops working at the exact time that I install Kaspersky Endpoint Security 8.1.0.831 with NetAgent 9.2.69.
Other machines with the same programs in the same sector don't have this problem. I installed the newest version of Skype 6.x.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your policy settings can be too strict. Skype can be pretty aggressive with it's network behavior, so heuristics can false detect some rogue activity.

Try these steps first:

- Check your policy settings to see if they interfere with Skype - https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-for-windows
- If you have application control turned on - check the status of the Skype app. Is it trusted? If not - check the info to see why - maybe the Skype version is shady. If everything looks good - up the privileges to Trusted and see if you can connect.
- Otherwise, try turning components off one by one and see which one interferes with the application. Then, add it to exclusions as a temporary workaround and submit a request to Kaspersky support: http://support.kaspersky.com/helpdesk.html They will instruct you how to collect the debug info and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not monitoring all encrypted connections.  I changed this option and it blocked me from Skype and installing a piece of software from Autodesk.  Go into "Additional"  then "Network" and look for the "Encrypted connections scanning".